# Android Studio.How to disable all system buttons(Back, Home and Menu) for activity?

Tags: android, system, android-button

I have seen many solutions to this problem, but the solutions were for older versions. Is there any way to disable the system buttons Back, Home and Menu for one activity? I am programming for android 7 and above.

Comment: You can't disable Home button you can only disable Back Button and Menu

Comment: @YaqoobBhatti,wow,and how I can disable Back and Menu buttons?Edit:but I can come back in app after home button click,right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try override onKeyDown.This can intercept back button and do something you want.Also override onBackPressed() can intercept back button.

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
  
        do something;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the menu button and home button I'm not sure if still can intercept in now days.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to lock the com.android.systemui package